# Want to print two different div using for loop using one single db object

Tags: codeigniter, for-loop

I have two different div for two different blogs. One need to be only once, and the second one need to be print again and again. I am not able to write the loop for the same. So the first section need to get rendered once and second needs to get repeated again and again.

I have tried many loops and methods but none of them are working properly for me.

Not able to form any loop.

```
<section class="blog_main">
        <div class="blog_left">
            <img src="uploads/blogs/<?php echo $mythical[0]->image;?>">
        </div>
        <div class="blog_right">
            <h1><a href="#">Scaling design sprints: Spreading the gospel 4 min read</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In quas similique atque labore illum libero vero
                sit, esse adipisci quis accusantium quisquam eos velit corporis doloremque soluta ducimus ipsum
                voluptas?</p>
            <h4>4 min read.</h4>
            <a href="#" class="author">ARTICLE BY <span>DANIEL SPATZEK</span> IN <span>WEB DESIGN</span> - OCTOBER
                02</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>

<section class="same_sec">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        <?php
         if(count($mythical)>0){ 

         foreach($mythical as $mythicals){       
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/blog_detail/<?php echo $mythicals->slug;?>">
                    <div class="small_curve_section">
                        <div class="image_S">
                            <img src="uploads/blogs/<?php echo $mythicals->image;?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content_for_curve">
                            <h3><?php echo $mythicals->blog_heading;?></h3>
                            <div class="bookar_mark_White">
                                <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
                                <div class="div_black">
                                    <p><?php echo $mythicals->read_time;?>min read</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
            <?php }} ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Sir, I want to know the loop. I am unable to draft the loop properly.

Comment: Section blog main needs to be printed once and the sectio same_sec needs to get repeated.

Comment: what is count($mythical) value ? did you check it ?

Comment: then you have to run the loop outside of same-sec

Comment: If I will start the loop from the same sec, then it will be repeated again and again.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Edit code like this..

"same_sec" will loop upto to the count($mythical) array.

```
<?php
if(count($mythical)>0){ 

    foreach($mythical as $mythicals){       
?>
<section class="same_sec">
    <div class="row no-gutters">

        <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/blog_detail/<?php echo $mythicals->slug;?>">
                <div class="small_curve_section">
                    <div class="image_S">
                        <img src="uploads/blogs/<?php echo $mythicals->image;?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content_for_curve">
                        <h3><?php echo $mythicals->blog_heading;?></h3>
                        <div class="bookar_mark_White">
                            <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
                            <div class="div_black">
                                <p><?php echo $mythicals->read_time;?>min read</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
<?php 
    }
} 
?>
```